# connection between classic asp and flash fails

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, asp-classic

Connection between flash and classic asp times out on explorer. It looks like something to do with the security settings of the IE, but I've tried every security settings possible and nothing solves the problem. This problem only happens on one specific computer. On all other computers all works fine. I've also copied the security settings from one computer (where all works fine) to the problematic computer. It didn't help!
Any ideas?

Comment: additional info: the problematic computer has windows 7 and IE10.

Comment: Classic ASP is server side code, so if your problem is machine specific and browser specific ASP is unlikely be the source of the problem.  Are you running an old version of Flash?

Comment: yes, it's a very old version of flash.

Comment: So the fact that it's a very old version of Flash is somehow not pertinent to your question? I guess that means that you don't need to tell us what version that is, nor do you need to communicate what happens if you upgrade to the current version? Oh well...